# Does switching off electrical devices while the main switch is still ON do any good?

Tags: electricity

Suppose the main switch of a TV is ON, but the TV is OFF, will it make any difference than when the TV is ON. If the switch is ON, but I switch OFF the TV, will it save electricity than when the TV is ON? Thank You.

Comment: Can you give a specific example?

Comment: yes it does. now regulations has required most devices to "sleep" efficiently so when devices are turned off but remain connected, the must not take too much power.

Comment: I think what you are asking is if I have a device such as my TV that is plugged into the wall and the mains switch is 'on' but has been switched 'off' on the device. Does this consume more power than it would if the mains switch on the wall were switched 'off'.  If so then I think this is a valid question but your question does not quite say this, making it unclear. Please edit your question and there is a good chance it will be re-opened.

Comment: @WarrenHill now sir?

Comment: I would be happy to re open this question but it takes more than one, I think 5 if I remember correctly.  Lets hope a few more people agree with me.

Answer (score 2):

Many appliances these days have a soft power switch. That is, when turned off at the appliance, it goes into a kind of "sleep" mode. The business end of the appliance is turned off, saving power, but at least part of the power supply and circuitry is still on.

For example, when you use your remote to turn off your TV, most of the TV shuts down, but it still has to use some power to continue to listen for the remote so you can turn it back on again.

When in sleep mode, the power used is usually tiny. However, with enough appliances, over the course of a year, that can add up to a considerable amount.

The latter may be trivial. However, the bigger issue is the possibility of a fault in the appliance causing it to power up, or worse, fail and start a fire. As such it is prudent to physically remove the power from appliances when they are to be left unattended for any significant length of time. For example, when you go on vacation.

Some folks still routinely unplug at night, which is of course a real pain if the appliance has a real-time clock in it.

BTW: I used to own a SONY CRT TV, that had the annoying habit of turning itself on once in a while. Worse, when it did, it came up with no signal so just white noise on the screen and a loud hiss just like in [Poltergeist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poltergeist_(2015_film)). Very spooky at 3a.m.

Since that TV gobbled large watts, coming home from vacation and finding it on was rather disturbing.

[image]

**ADDITION:**

A more modern reason to unplug has to do with smart technologies that are voice activated and network connected. These devices are capable of [monitoring your conversations](https://www.cnet.com/news/samsungs-warning-our-smart-tvs-record-your-living-room-chatter/) and communicating information back to some marketing department somewhere. Depending on your paranoia level, that may be important to you. Personally, I pity whomever may be listening to any of the conversations between Me and the Mrs.

Comment: Sir so turning off atleast the device saves electricity. right? thank you.

Comment: Yes, but if it's a new device it won't be much. [EU regulations](https://ec.europa.eu/energy/en/topics/energy-efficiency/energy-efficient-products/standby) say that devices sold from 2013 onwards should consume no more than 0.5W in standby mode, which in the UK equates to about £0.50 per year. But the more devices you have the more it adds up. The exceptions are network-connected devices that remain active, which must consume no more that 3 to 12W depending on type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Obvious It will reduce your Electricity bill. Because, Current need a close path to flow through the circuit. When you turn off your electric device let us say fan, then it will break the path so current can not flow and You will pay less electricity bill.

This is for simple electric device. But like @Trevor said for electronic device your device will go in power down mode. So majority of the circuit will get disconnected from power supply except some sensors which will help circuit to come in normal mode.